# plotting more than one plot with different axes types

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-2.7

I have the following code but I want them to be on the same graph but different subplots.

What's the simplest way to create different axes?

```
from pylab import *

figure(0)
x =1
y = 2
plot(x, y, marker ='^', linewidth=4.0)
xlabel('time (s)')
ylabel('cost ($)')
title('cost vs. time')

figure(1)

x = 4
y = 100
plot(x, y, marker ='^', linewidth=4.0)
xlabel('cost ($)')
ylabel('performance (miles/hr) ')
title('cost vs. time')


show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pyplot.subplots`. I am using the `pyplot` api which is recommended for programming (see: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#pyplot)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
x = 1
y = 2
ax0.plot(x, y, marker ='^')
ax0.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax0.set_ylabel('cost ($)')
ax0.set_title('Plot 1')

x = 4
y = 100
ax1.plot(x, y, marker ='^')
ax1.set_xlabel('cost ($)')
ax1.set_ylabel('performance (miles/hr)')
ax1.set_title('Plot 2')

fig.suptitle('cost vs. time')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.1, wspace=0.25)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting_plot]

Comment: Awesome, but what's the command to label these subplots and give each one a specific title...                                                 Thanks